# Nutch fetch job failed with Http 403

Tags: java, nutch, robots.txt

I am crawling the site https://www.recode.net/ and during the fetch job the log showing :

```
fetching https://www.recode.net/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
robots.txt whitelist not configured.
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
..........................
..........................
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Fetcher: throughput threshold retries: 5
fetcher.maxNum.threads can't be < than 50 : using 50 instead
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=3
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
fetch of https://www.recode.net/ failed with: Http code=403, url=https://www.recode.net/
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0
-activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=0
-activeThreads=0
Fetcher: finished at 2017-09-21 15:39:07, elapsed: 00:00:03
```

And I didn't get any data to index.
I checked with the site's `robots.txt` and it's fine and not disallowing my user agent. Also, I am not using any regex to filter url.

Comment: Obviously, the host www.recode.net responds with [HTTP 403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), probably because of having identified the request coming from a bot.

Comment: why is it so ? But they are not blocking using robots.txt

Comment: If some "bad" bots ignore the robots.txt or load the server with too many requests, the site admins may have decided to block bots generally and allow only a fix list of bots identified by user-agent string and/or IP range.

Comment: I faced the similar problem. @Abhishek were you able to find a solution for this?